# Query Notification Internals

Tags: sql-server, queue, sql-server-2014, service-broker

I'm looking into using [Query Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server) as a light(er) weight way of identifying when data in a table changes. I know they use Service Broker, and (although I have difficulty explaining exactly why) they do look like they'd be preferable to something like CDC or Triggers.

Query Notifications get set up by providing the database with a query, which sends a notification "[...when the results of [the provided] query change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175110(v=sql.105))".

That to me sounds like they're saying whatever query you've given it, is going to be run over and over and over. I think I'm probably misinterpreting what precisely SQL does under the covers with that query to monitor said changes, but I couldn't find anything online about what's actually taking place. I'm hoping it's something like it parses the query and sets up super duper lightweight "triggers" on any object referenced in the query, but since I don't know, it's making me reticent to want to use the feature.

Is anyone familiar enough with Service Broker and the Query Notification functionality to explain how the database engine watches for changes in the provided query?

Comment: This article might help. https://web.archive.org/web/20090426220055/http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/ though the picture showing the execution plan is too small to read and the original image no longer is available. But you could set up your own test

Comment: Why don't you use triggers, store data changes into a table and print them with PHP or other language?

Comment: @AlvaroParra quite a few reasons, but irrelevant since that's not what I'm interested in here.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks; reading that article now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is based on the same technology as materialized (indexed) views. When you set up a QN for the query "Select ... from .... where" the engine sets up a fake indexed view with the same query. Whenever you run any DML, the execution plan has to maintain the 'fake' indexed view data and generates the plan accordingly. When (and if) the DML execution actually attempts to update a row in the fake indexed view, this is a sign that the original query is likely to have changed the results and the notification is fired. The 'fake' indexed view is then removed. Needles the say, the 'fake' indexed view is never materialized (no actual rows exist).

This is why the restrictions of what query can subscribe for QN are almost identical with indexed view restrictions.

The article linked by Martin explains the same, but leaving this here as an answer for future ref.